# How can I set sigma parameter in xarray curvefit?

Tags: python, limit, curve-fitting, python-xarray

I want to fix the limits of my dataset fitting, using the `curvefit` function of Xarray. In the [documentation](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.curvefit.html) it is said that the function accepts `**kwargs` to pass to `scipy curve_fit`, but passing a value for `sigma` I get this error.

> TypeError: curvefit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sigma'

Comment: That's supposed to be a dictionary, so probably `xarray.Dataset.curvefit( ..., kwargs={sigma : <yourdatahere>})`

Comment: That said...some example code would be nice.

Comment: I also found the same issue solved [here](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/6891). Maybe the documentation should be clearer, since it is not specified that a dictionary is expected and the syntax to pass the arguments. Thanks for the comment @mikuszefski.

Comment: So you solved it. Good. And you are right, the docs are not really clear. I was expecting this behaviour knowing it from other modules and functions. (and to be honest, I also checked the source as linked in the docs. Definitively not a standard-user solution)